# cant display block in product-view page

Tags: blocks, navigation, static-block

I'm trying to display a little carousel in the top navigation, the .phtml file calls a static-block which calls a block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

It works fine in homepage and category pages, but it fails to display this block in the product-view pages.
Do you know why this is happening?.

Thanks
.-

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, product listing won't show up in product view page unless the category_id is the same as the current product's category id.

If you open a product which belongs to category with id 12 it should show the block.

This is because of the code in magento's List.php:

```
if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to call a product list in product-view page?.

Comment: You can create a new block overriding the product list block without these restriction in the code and call that block instead of the default product list block in the view page.